# Exporting a network produced with visNetwork for R

Tags: r, wordpress, graph, shiny, visnetwork

could you please help me?

I want to draw a network that I'm studying in an interactive format for using in talks and on my website. For that purpose, I'm using the R package visNetwork and the following code:

```
network = visNetwork(nodes2, links2) %>%
visLayout(hierarchical = F,
        improvedLayout = T)
visSave(network, file = "oilint.html")
```

The code works fine and I get a HTML file that opens correctly on my browser.

However, when I try to export the same network in PNG (or JPG) format, it does not work. The code for that is:

```
network = visNetwork(nodes2, links2) %>%
visLayout(hierarchical = F,
        improvedLayout = T) %>%
visExport(type = "png", name = "oil.int", 
      float = "left", label = "Save network", background = "purple", style= "")
```

I get the network on the plot window with the "Save network button":

[image: example network]

But when I try to save it, I get a blank screen in *shiny* for RStudio:

[image: blank screen]

My questions are:

1. How to I fix this problem with shiny, so I can export the network as a PNG image?
2. In what format should I export the network, so I can post it on my Wordpress website?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem. My workaround is: `visSave` to save to `html`, open with Chrome and right-click -> `Save as Image`. `png` should be fine.